# How to order wordpress tags in a specific order

Tags: wordpress

I have 6 tags in wordpress and want to order them like this, where the numbers are the tag id's:

5, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6

Not getting it to work in Wordpress.

wp_list_categories('exclude=3&orderby=5,1,2,4,6');

No error, just not working...

Answer (score 0):

The orderby field is for a specific attribute of a category, like 'name' in a predefined order.  If you want to order in the way you're asking (5,3,1,2,4,6), you'll have to do this manually.

Comment: You'll have to use get_categories() using the exclude argument like you're already using in wp_list_categories(), reorder them, and then format the results however you need them.  You can look at the code for wp_list_categories() to get an idea of how Wordpress does the formatting (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L0)

Comment: Was wondering, since I know the Category Names if I could just hardcode them into the template?